# Dropwizard - Liquibase exception changelog parse exception

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase, dropwizard

I'm getting below error in my test:

```
com.hello.resources.SettingsResourceTest > shouldCreateRetrieveAndDeleteSetting FAILED
    liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException
        Caused by: java.io.IOException
```

This is when I run a test with Gradle with:

```
./gradlew test
```

Is there a reason why I'm getting liquibase exception? Also how do I debug this?

Comment: You sure that the Liquibase XML file didn't change?

Comment: @Makoto it's h2 but I don't see anything there

Comment: You should try to set the log level for liquibase to `DEBUG` to get more info where the parser has problems to parse your xml. I don't know dropwizard so I can't tell where to set the log level there. But I you can't find out you can also just leave out the dropwizard wrapper around liquibase and run liquibase from command line. Feed it with the same xml and then see where the parsing fails...

Comment: The test code would be very useful here. Also, gradle generates a report of failed tests with more details. There you can see the message of the exception which should be more explanatory.